# how to purge / shrink .idb tables

Tags: mysql, innodb

I know this has been asked many times but, what is the proper configuration *to succesfully purge / shrink .idb tables?*

I have tried to use `optimize table table_name` but after the query the .idb tables stays the same size.

This is my configuration at `[mysql]` in `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=500M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
query_cache_size = 268435456
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=134217728
innodb_file_per_table=1
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Are you talking about the innodb file for a table or the "global" ibd files? 

There is a good read about this here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/25/how-to-reclaim-space-in-innodb-when-innodb_file_per_table-is-on/

Comment: the files that are located at /var/lib/mysql/database_name

Comment: @sysadmiral - i have tried that already. the .ibd tables did not shrink / purge. it stays the same.

Comment: Then they are probably shrunk down as much as they can be. If you have a separate database server for testing you can dump the table and import it on the test database and check the ibd size. It will probably be a similar size.

If it is smaller then you can do the same process on the live db. Dump the table and reimport it.

Comment: @sysadmiral - but the .ibd size is getting larger because eveyday we input data. is there other options that i should do?

Comment: Apart from running `optimize table` and doing a dump/reimport I am not sure you can do anything else to reclaim this space.

As you say if you are inputting data it will continue to grow. You cannot avoid that.

Comment: To state the obvious - if you insert new data, the file will grow.. If you delete some rows, the freed space will be reused by new inserts later, but if you do not delete, there is nothing to shrink.

Comment: Do you have at least 24GB of RAM?  If not, then those settings are too high.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is rarely needed or even useful for InnoDB tables.  You are probably experiencing that.

Answer (score 4):

To shrink an .ibd file it's enough to run `ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE INNODB`. It will rebuild the tablespace and the new one will be the most compact. I think `OPTIMIZE TABLE` does exactly the same internally. `ALTER TABLE` however is preferred because you can use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-online-schema-change.html) to avoid blocking the table.

To get better understanding how data use the tablespace I would recommend InnoDB tools https://github.com/jeremycole/innodb_ruby

For example, to check how many pages are user by PRIMARY secondary indexes and how many free pages:

```
# /usr/local/bin/innodb_space -f actor.ibd space-extents-illustrate

  Start Page ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
           0 │███▄▂░░                                                         │
             ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

Legend (█ = 1 page):
  Page Type                                                         Pages    Ratio
  █ System                                                              3   42.86%
  █ Index 15                                                            1   14.29%
  █ Index 16                                                            1   14.29%
  ░ Free space                                                          2   28.57%
```